# How to make a replication in MariaDB with windows 10? Error 1067 with the service

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, database-replication, mariadb-10.5

I have been looking for how to create a database replication with MariaDB but the steps I find on the official page of how to do it https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-up-replication/ give me an error in this He passed:

Example that enables replication for MariaDB
Add the following to your my.cnf file and restart the database.

```
[mariadb]
log container
server_id = 1
log-basename = master1
binlog-format = mixed
```

**When I change the file, I get a 1067 error when restarting the MariaDB service. All the examples I find, are solutions for Linux, also try changing the environment variables. Is there a solution to this error? Or is there another way to create a replication?**

Answer (score 1):

I already resolved it!. The error was because I followed the tutorial deleting what the default my.ini file contains and I replaced it with what the tutorial told me and what you have to do is add the new configuration below to the file and that's it.

Then the same is done with the slave, remembering to change the server number.